# python, instance dynamic module.class from given path package and call dynamic method

Tags: python, dynamic, import, load

```
package_path = '/home/foo/bar/'
module_class = 'hello.World'
method = 'something'
```

first, i want to import the `hello` **module** what it is inside of the `package_path` (`/home/foo/bar/`)

then, i must instantiate the class `World` at this module

and finally i should run the `something()` method on the new **world_instance_object**

any idea for do that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: this can be duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: any way for import a package (not module) from path string and then, import the module.Class for them?

Comment: package and module are imported same way. class is module attribute, method is class atribute. Use `getattr` for obtaining object's attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to manipulate `sys.path` and to keep all the extra modules you import from cluttering up `sys.modules`, I'd suggest using `execfile()` for this.  Something like this (untested code):

```
import os.path

def load_and_call(package_path, module_class, method_name):
    module_name, class_name = module_class.split(".")
    module_globals = {}
    execfile(os.path.join(package_path, module_name + ".py"), module_globals)
    return getattr(module_globals[class_name](), method_name, lambda: None)()
```

You could add some code to cache the parsed objects using a dictionary, if a file will be used more than once (again, untested):

```
def load_and_call(package_path, module_class, method_name, _module_cache={}):
    module_name, class_name = module_class.split(".")
    py_path = os.path.join(package_path, module_name + ".py")
    module_globals = _module_cache.setdefault(py_path, {})
    if not module_globals:
        execfile(py_path, module_globals)
    return getattr(module_globals[class_name](), method_name, lambda: None)()
```